# How can I commit only part of a file in Perforce?

Tags: version-control, perforce

How are you doing this task in Perforce ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't. As with some other version control systems, you operate on a per file basis. That is, a single file is the smallest entity / unit of work possible.

I'd think that they all act on the presumption that changes to a file are atomic (most good version control systems will even use a commit of *multiple* files as an atomic operation).

If you only want to commit some parts, you essentially have to create a copy of your modified file, where you reset all those parts that you don't want to change back to their original content/text. Or better yet, only change one thing at a time and eventually separately commit those changes.

Comment: Well, git supports adding to the index (and then committing) only part of a file ;) http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_adding.html

Comment: Wow, one more (fancy, albeit ;-) reason to look into git.

Comment: sometimes I hate perforce for complicating things like that. I just wanted to commit bit by bit while keeping the file checked out, nothing that complicated. I believe its possible, but developers were just lazy to not implement such a basic tool.

Answer (score 25):

Yes, you can't do that.

The only thing you can do would be:

- shelve your file **without** reverting it
- open the diff of your file, and remove any other changes that those you want to submit
- submit the resulting file which contains only the part you wanted to
- unshelve the shelved version of the file
- get the latest revision of it, and resolve (P4 should be able to auto-resolve it)

Then you still have the file in checkout, with the other modifications.

Comment: Beware that p4 really does not like your file to be in multiple changelists.  It is easy when doing this procedure to accidentally lose the stashed version when you don't notice it follow you to a new changelist

Comment: Yes, this is the required workflow. However, the non-existence of this feature essentially encourages developers to simply dump the current changes as one big chunk. This makes code reviews practically impossible in my experience. In theory, one could write a small tool that supports selective submits (doing the described behavior behind your back). Unfortunately, no one wrote this tool, yet...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't.
I can't fault perforce for not having that feature as it's quite old software, but I can most certainly despise it for it. "We don't use perforce around here, right?" is a perfectly good question for my next job interview.
The first distributed VCS I used was Mercurial, then I switched to git on the basis of this feature alone.